# How access variables/functions in .aspx frame from .asp classic frame with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp-classic, frames

I have a frameset that contains .asp classic pages and one that contains a .aspx page.  I want to access the .aspx's functions and variables in the "menu frame" from the "top frame" using JavaScript.  When there was an .asp in the "menu frame", all you need to do is reference: self.menu.someVariable or top.menu.someFunction().  Those are now unavailable in the JavaScript of the .aspx.

How do I reference the functions and variables in the .aspx from an .asp in another frame?

In index.asp, the top level:

```
<frameset id="colSet" >
<noframes>
</noframes>
<frame id="menu" name="menu" src="idx_menu.aspx">
<frameset id="rowSet" >
<frame name="header" src="idx_header.asp">
<frame name="command" src="idx_command.asp">
<frame name="main" src="default.asp" >
<frame name="message" src="idx_message.asp">
</frameset>
</frameset>
```

JavaScript in the top frame, index.asp.  This is called by the idx_menu.aspx on the onload event, so the document is loaded when these are called:

```
function menuLoaded() {
self.menu.idxDisplayMenu('');  // error with undefined
top.menu.idxDisplayMenu('');  // same error
top.menu.swfVersion = '5';    // also an error
}
```

JavaScript in the menu frame, idx_menu.aspx:

```
var swfVersion = '';

function pageLoaded() {
    top.menuLoaded();
}
function idxDisplayMenu(message) {
alert(message);
}
```

.aspx is the same code as the old idx_menu.asp in regard to this example.

Comment: Are the two pages from different domains?  I really don't see the "asp" vs. "aspx" as being the significant factor here.  "Those are now unavailable in the JavaScript " - what exactly do you mean by this?  What happenedc when you tried that?

Comment: Same domain and I didn't see the the two as different either.  But the code in the top frame is calling the same function as before.  It's just that the menu page has changed from .asp to .aspx (same functions and variables as before).  "Unavailable" just means when I reference a "those" functions or variables as I did in the past, the result is "undefined".

Comment: I think we'll need to see some actual code.

Comment: Edited with code sample.  Just trying to upgrade idx_menu.asp to .aspx so the code is basically the same... exact as far as this problem goes.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I feel stupid!  The JavaScript was in .js files and while I could see the code in the debugger, it wasn't reaching it for some reason.  I used the following and the code worked:

```
<script src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/include/scripts.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I wasn't using the ResolveUrl before and hard coding the location.